# Cannot wrap element around XQuery output

Tags: xquery, exist-db

Returning to XQuery after a long hiatus.

```
let $root := <a:b xmlns:a="ans" xmlns:c="cns"/>
     for $prefix in in-scope-prefixes($root)[not(. = ('xml', 'xsi'))]
      return 
          namespace-uri-for-prefix($prefix,$root) ! 
              <param name="{$prefix}" value="{.}"/>
```

gives the expected

```
<param name="a" value="ans"/>  
<param name="c" value="cns"/>
```

But if I try to wrap an element around that output like below nothing is returned

```
<parameters>{
let $root := <a:b xmlns:a="ans" xmlns:c="cns"/>
     for $prefix in in-scope-prefixes($root)[not(. = ('xml', 'xsi'))]
      return 
          namespace-uri-for-prefix($prefix,$root) ! 
              <param name="{$prefix}" value="{.}"/>
}</parameters>
```

So what is wrong and how do I wrap the output in a parameters element?

Comment: It returns the expected result for me

Comment: Does not work when pasted here so maybe it is an eXist-db problem http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/eXide/index.html

Comment: Yeah, I was running in MarkLogic. Curious if it works in eXist if you let a variable with the sequence of elements, like this: `let $root := <a:b xmlns:a="ans" xmlns:c="cns"/>
let $params :=
     for $prefix in in-scope-prefixes($root)[not(. = ('xml', 'xsi'))]
     return 
       namespace-uri-for-prefix($prefix,$root) ! 
              <param name="{$prefix}" value="{.}"/>
return               
  <parameters>{$params}</parameters>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try letting a variable with the sequence of `<param>` elements, and return the `<parameters>` element referencing that variable instead of putting the FLWOR inline.

You shouldn't have to do that. I was able to generate the desired output in MarkLogic with your original code, but it seems necessary for eXist to generate the desired output.

```
xquery version "3.0" encoding "UTF-8";
let $root := <a:b xmlns:a="ans" xmlns:c="cns"></a:b>
let $params :=
     for $prefix in in-scope-prefixes($root)[not(. = ('xml', 'xsi'))]
     return 
       namespace-uri-for-prefix($prefix,$root) ! 
              <param name="{$prefix}" value="{.}"/>
return 
  <parameters>{ $params }</parameters>
```

Comment: Did not work in exist-db. This links straight to their XQuery IDE http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/eXide/index.html you can paste it and see.

Comment: Oh, gotcha. The code suggested in my comment works. I'll update this answer.